# Line Break Between Components in Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm having some issues with layout managers in swing. I would like for the below components to be in a layout manager so the jtextarea is on the line below the combo box and the button.

[image]

In other words, like this:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
panel.add(jcb);
panel.add(go);
panel.add(scrollPane);
add(panel);
```

Comment: Read about layouts https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 3):

Don't use just one JPanel. Put the top line of components into one JPanel. Give the main GUI a BoxLayout, and then add the top JPanel first and then your JScrollPane that holds the JTextArea next. Most important, read the layout manager tutorial and experiment with this.